# Using On-Perm Artifactory as a docker registry while behind the Azure Application Proxy

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, artifactory

Artifactory 6.0.1 PRO

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
```

We have setup artifactory with several docker instances.  We do have SSO enabled to our SAML authentication system but now we cannot seem to login to the docker instance:

I do have DOCKER_OPTS=" --insecure-registry"

```
$ docker login artifactory.foo.internal
Username: admin
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get https://artifactory.foo.internal/v2/: unknown: Unsupported docker repository request for 'v2'
```

No matter what I use in username/password I get the same error.

I have also tried using artifactory.foo.internal:443

We're using Tomcat as a direct connection.  Docker configuration is set to PATH.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you tried? What is not working? Do you need High Availability? Start here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+Artifactory

Comment: I replaced the original question with a simpler one ... this is completely internal connection without going through Azure... to remove one set of the complexity.

Comment: I know this problem is very old. But did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Martin I believe, we had to use "docker.artifactory.foo.internal" as the DNS and configure that in the artifactory nginx to map it to the right path.